# How to add onSuccess and onFailure to getJSON()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

The following code makes a API call to the server and gets the response as JSON. Then it turns the JSON object to a string and parse the same using respective jQuery functions and store it to the local storage and load a page. I want to do this on success and throw an error message on failure. I tried `.done()` and `.fail()` functions but it throws an uncaught expression error.

```
 $.getJSON(apiURL,

                {'call':'login','email':uname, 'pwd':password},

                function(data){

                   localStorage.setItem('testObject', data.id);                   

                   $.ui.loadContent("home", null, null, "fade");  

                }
            );
```

Can someone how can I add onSuccess and onFailure to this code ?

Comment: Why are you converting the data to a string then back to an object again?

Comment: I tried JSON parsing directly. It didn't work. The JSON format that I got from the api didn't allowed me to access directly. So I first make it to string and then parse the data.

Comment: @deadshot: `data` will be an object by the time you see it, because jQuery will parse it for you. Stringifying and then parsing again is pointless.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for your comment. I appreciate that.  I tried something like this https://jsbin.com/wexuqusume/2/edit?html,output but it didn't work. When I stringify and parse, it worked.

Comment: @deadshot: You don't want to parse it! Just use `data` the way you're using `parsed`, it's *already* been parsed for you.

Comment: Got it. Thanks alot :) . I will change my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I tried .done() and .fail() functions but it throws an uncaught expression error.**

`.done` and `.fail` are indeed how you would do this, it sounds like your code trying to use them had a syntax error.

```
$.getJSON(apiURL, { 'call': 'login', 'email': uname, 'pwd': password })
    .done(function() {
        // Handle success
        var obj = JSON.stringify(data);                 // <=== These lines are
        var parsed = JSON.parse(obj);                   // <=== completely pointless

        localStorage.setItem('testObject', parsed.id);

        //alert(localStorage.getItem('testObject'));

        $.ui.loadContent("home", null, null, "fade");
    })
    .fail(function() {
        // Handle failure
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. This should work. The mistake I did was I terminated $.getJSON() partially before doing .done().

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
$.getJSON(apiURL, { 'call': 'login', 'email': uname, 'pwd': password })
.done(function() {
    var data = JSON.stringify(data); 
    //...  
});
.fail(function(){
  console.log('failure');
});
```

You can also do

```
result = $.get('url',{param1:'param'});
result.done(function(data){
   //handle success
});
result.done(function(){
   //handle failure
});
```